# Prevent Angular to rerender components which are copied from within NgRx reducers

Tags: angular, ngrx

My problem lies in the following: we have to copy the state in the NgRx reducer for immutability. But because of this Angular rerenders components, event those which are not changed in the properties, they only have been recreated by spread operator or lodash clone. I preserve some state in my components such as counters, which I don't want to store in the NgRx store, but I lose them due to the rerender. I have tried trackBy function for NgFor directive and various implementations of reducers but they do not seem to work. Can you please help me approach the problem?

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Can you give more information which documents your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use memorized selectors (default createSelector does it) and change the component's `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.
In that case component will be rerendered only when the pointer has been changed.

Also instead of deep clone I would suggest only to change pointers to changed data.

```js
interface State {
  ob1: Obj;
  ob2: Obj;
}
// ...
const newState = {...state, ob2: newOb2};
```

which keeps pointer to `ob1` as it was, but shakes state change for the `ob2`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot!